# Find Results in excel copy the rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help copying data from one excel worksheet to another. For example:

Sample Data

**__*A*__B___C**

1 aaa bbb ddd

2 bbb ccc eee

3 ccc fff rrr

4 ccc fff ttt

5 ddd eee ggg

6 aaa ddd eee

7 bbb fff hhh

8 eee eee eee

So for the above records if I do a 'CTRL + F' and search to find All 'eee' the results will show 6 instances in C2, B5, C6, A8, B8, C8

Now I want to copy the whole of rows 2,5,6 and 8 to another worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you need please do the following (assuming your data is located in columns A:C starting row 2, i.e. there are headers):

1. Type in D2 (additional column): `=IF(OR(A2:C2="eee"),1,0)`, but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).
2. Autofill formula as required.
3. Add filter to the whole A:D range.
4. Apply filter to column D for value `1`.
5. Copy entire filtered columns A:C and paste anywhere - only filtered rows will be copied.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qscwbf5kbnwi5pa/Filtering3Columns.xlsx

Comment: One other thing though, can I edit that formula to search for multiple keywords such as for 'eee' or 'fff' and the result for 'eee' to be 1 and for 'fff' to be '2'
Many Thanks!

Comment: @amateur what if you have BOTH `eee` and `fff` in the same row - what you should get? 1? 2? or 1+2? be more specific.

Comment: aah didn't think about that, never mind....what you have answered already does the trick. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @amateur please download the updated sample using the same link - I added 2 more solutions: 2nd will count SUM of match indexes, 3rd will count number of total matches in a single row. Hope that was helpful)

Comment: Thanks for that...slight problem now :( the data that I have is not 'eee' and 'fff' in fact it's a date format '25/03/2011' and '24/04/2011' and so on....but I'm only concerned about the month and year...so display 1 for all 'Mar 11' data and 2 for all 'Apr 11' can you help with this please?

Comment: @amateur in that case I need exact sample of your data. And for the future - do not hesitate to provide the input as close to the task as possible: smth you consider as not at all important usually means totally different approach for the developer. I'd better start a new thread, since this one is marked as solved, and would list all the reqs and wants there together with exact sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks, posted a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733602/microsoft-excel-array-formula-with-dates

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me... a simple solution:

1. Select/highlight the data you want to search
2. Press ctrl +h for Replace
3. Enter the string you want to find in "Find What".
4. Select "Replace with" Format, then Format > Fill and choose a background fill, doesn't matter what color.  Then click [Replace All].
5. Then choose on the Excel menu > Data > Sort on "Cell Color", 
   Order (the color you chose from step 4 above) and then "On Top" or      "On Bottom" - whatever you want, click [Ok].

Now all the data you wanted is all in one block of rows. Copy and paste to another worksheet as required.

Comment: Thx. This worked perfectly. Simple. Straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. I liked this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called `VLOOKUP` just take the Excel-help, theres everything explained

Comment: VLOOKUP is a function that searches for value in the left-most column of table_array and returns the value in the same row based on the index_number.

I need something like a macro perhaps where I can specify a criteria (keyword) to search for, it returns the data and copies all rows containing that criteria to a new sheet.

Comment: ah.. sry.. misunderstood ^^ didnt work with excel for a long time, so i think i cant you help then... Will have a look, when my workday is done. But will take a while...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was this: Using the option "Sort & Filter" located in the right upper corner. Then you can filter any column by any criteria you like. By doing that only the filtered rows appear on the spread sheet (the rest are still there but just hidden). From there you can easily copy and paste the entire rows.

Comment: But how does this filter for "eee" in column A **or** column B **or** column C?