# Microsoft Excel Array Formula with dates

Tags: excel, ms-office

I need the following array for a Date type:

```
=IF(OR(A2:C2="Mar 12"),1,0)
```

Sample Data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhoDU0OTM87sdHR3RGw3NTJacEV1OEt5OWZTWTBYUFE&usp=sharing

Looking at the sample data, in Column E I want an array formula that would look into columns B to D and search for results that contain 'May 12' and display true or false (1 or 0) in column E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will meet your needs - type in D2:

```
=IF(SUM((MONTH(A2:C2)=5)*(YEAR(A2:C2)=2013))>0,1,0)
```

but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).

Specify month and year as you wish)

Comment: Glad to help buddy) Hope you learned the lesson of proper task formulation)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for (noticed the date format was dd/mm/yyyy so I adjusted):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"12/5/2013")>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Edit:

For just month and day:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A1:C1)=5)*(DAY(A1:C1)=12))>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Month and year:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A1:C1)=5)*(YEAR(A1:C1)=2012))>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: How do I do it without specifying a 'Day' though? Just month and year?