# Find string in cell contents and copy the rows to another sheet

Tags: excel

This is branching off of the question [Find Results in excel copy the rows to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731185/find-results-in-excel-copy-the-rows-to-another-sheet/14731575#14731575). That has a solution for exact matches but not "contains" matches.  There is also a branch from that prior entry, but specific to date format.

I am going to copy the contents of of original entry with an extra requirement:

> "I need some help copying data from one Excel worksheet to another. For example:

```
____A_____B____C
1 xaaax xbbbx xdddx
2 xbbbx xcccx xeeex
3 xcccx xfffx xrrrx
4 xcccx xfffx xtttx
5 xdddx xeeex xgggx
6 xaaax xdddx xeeex
7 xbbbx xfffx xhhhx
8 xeeex xeeex xeeex
```

> Where every instance of "x" can be any string.
>
> So for the above records if I do a 'CTRL + F' and search to find All 'eee' the results will show 6 instances in C2, B5, C6, A8, B8, C8
>
> Now I want to copy the whole of rows 2,5,6 and 8 to another worksheet.
>
> If the entire cell contents were just the searched substring (ie: "eee") then the answer would be:
>
> (provided by Peter L.)
>   "To achieve what you need please do the following (assuming your data is located in columns A:C starting row 2, i.e. there are headers):
>
> Type in D2 (additional column): =IF(OR(A2:C2="eee"),1,0), but press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of usual ENTER - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in {} brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).
>   Autofill formula as required.
>   Add filter to the whole A:D range.
>   Apply filter to column D for value 1.
>   Copy entire filtered columns A:C and paste anywhere - only filtered rows will be copied."

HOWEVER, this solution only seems to work if the entire contents of the cell is equal to `eee`.  If I want to search for a substring, like search for `eee` in `alkjalkjeeeljkjl` I believe I need something else.

I have tried to use `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(` but I have reached the limits of my abilities, it seems that maybe search won't take in the range of A2:C2 for the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(D$1,A1),IFERROR(FIND(D$1,B1),FIND(D$1,C1)))
```

(Case sensitive) copied down, where D1 contains your search term.

Should be a means to identify which rows to copy (in conjunction with filter to exclude error values).

Comment: Thank you, this does the job.  I'll try to make it case insensitive, but other than that this will get me what I need.  For reference, A1, C1, and D1 are columns to be searched for the text, given row 1 is the starting row of the data.  (obvious from the question but I wanted to self-contain the answer a bit more).

Comment: Ah, replace "FIND" with "SEARCH" to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, change worksheets as necessary.

```
Sub SO()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim f As Long
Dim search As String
search = "eee"
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet5")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet6")

lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ws1

For i = 1 To lastRow1

f = InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1), search)

    If f > 0 Then
        lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ws2.Rows(lastRow2 + 1).Value = ws1.Rows(i).Value
    End If

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Doh. You have multiple columns. I only did A. So try a for each cell in range loop instead. Going home now XD